# Is it possible to avoid integers,floats and special characters using try-except statement only?

Tags: python, input, try-catch, except, letter

I'm trying to make a code that allows only letters. I know we can do this using `isalpha()` method. But, I'm looking for any other different solutions something like try-except?

Comment: Sounds like `isalpha` is exactly what you want. What are your requirements that it does not satisfy?

Comment: Why would you want to use an exception based strategy when the isapha() built-in is there precisely for this purpose?

Comment: Okay, guys! We agree with you. We don't need to try something new. **Learn what they told**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is reinventing the wheel, use `str.isalpha`

---

You could use `assert` and `AssertionError`

```
from string import ascii_letters

value = None
while True:
    try:
        value = input("Give a value: ")
        assert all(c in ascii_letters for c in value)
        break
    except AssertionError:
        print("Invalid input, try again")

print("Valid input:", value)
```

```
Give a value: aa!
Invalid input, try again
Give a value: !!!
Invalid input, try again
Give a value: !
Invalid input, try again
Give a value: rrTT
Valid input: rrTT
```