# Hey guys, how can I change my code wherein floats can also cause errors?

Tags: python

My code is that I want to return the list in ascending order and if there are strings, floats or any other invalid inputs, it will only return an empty list but if I include a float in the list, it also returns it and does not cause errors.

```
def sort_a_list(num_list):
    try:
        x = num_list
        if len(x) >= 0:
            return sorted(x)
        else:
            pass
    except:
        return []
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You are saying if a float is included in the list, return an empty list, but if _you_ give a float, then it shouldn't return an empty list. The interpreter has no way of knowing who you are without some input!

Comment: I mean if a float is included, it must return an empty list but the interpreter doesn't recognize the float as an invalid input but instead it includes it in the printed list.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is **impossible** with `try-except` statement unless you import the `string` module.
[See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71275406/is-it-possible-to-avoid-integers-floats-and-special-characters-using-try-except)
You may try using `isdigit()` method instead.
Here I have provided you a sample program what I mentioned above.

```
def sort_a_list(numlist):
    x = numlist 
    y = "".join(str(i) for i in x)
    if y.isdigit():
        return sorted(x)
    else:
        return []
numlist = [10,4,3,7,5,9]
print(sort_a_list(numlist))
```